# reactivemongo.core.errors.GenericDriverException: MongoError['socket disconnected']

Tags: mongodb, sockets, reactivemongo

Clients are using reactivemongo driver to connect to a mongodb replicaset (3 nodes) with a conenction pool of 10 per client.

Getting intermittent error as shown above from reactivemongo driver (version 10.0). Clients and MongoDB running in VMware VM.

Looking at MongoDB site production notes there may be some things to tweak: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/#prod-notes-ram for our CentOs boxes.

Wondering if anyone else has come across this error and/or if a fix was found ! Thanks.

Comment: We also have this problems (on reactivemongo 0.11.9), ignoring for now.